# How to use sitemap with https?

Tags: django, https

I decided to enable https in Django 1.11.4.

Thank you "Let's Encrypt".

So I redirected (301) all http requests to https.
Also, all non-www (http or https) is redirected (301) to https://www

It works fine exept my url https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml which doesn't work currently and since the https passing.

It returns a 500 error code and I don't really know why.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from example.sitemaps import *
from django.conf import settings



#Pour charger le favicon
media = settings.MEDIA

# Dictionary containing sitemap classes
sitemaps = {
    'products': ArticleSitemap(),

}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

sitemaps.py

```
#Generating Sitemap for Dynamic Urls

from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from wall.models import Articles

class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.7

    def items(self):
        return Articles.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-update')

    def lastmod(self, item): 
        return item.date
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites', #SiteMap
    'django.contrib.sitemaps', #SiteMap
```

It was working by http, so there is a modification to do, but I don't know the which one.

Comment: Since 5xx status codes mean server errors, you should really check your server logs for more information. If you still can't figure out what the problem is, you should include the logs in the question.

Comment: Nothing interesting in /var/log/apache2. I just have in access.log this line : 

91.69.234.118 - - [20/Dec/2018:16:22:06 +0100] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 500 3645 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue. I passed my Django into the debug mode and it returned :

> Site matching query does not exist

I concluded that the default `SITE_ID = 1` present in my settings.py was wrong.
Go to admin pannel of Django /admin/sites/ and edit the site.
The good ID is given by the URL on the browser.

Just to edit the `SITE_ID = 1` to `SITE_ID = 2` (in my case) and it works !

Answer (score 10):

It's too late but might helps to developers who came here from google.

You can add `protocol` as a class variable.

```
class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.7
    protocol = 'https' # <-- ADD THIS

    def items(self):
        ...
```

Also in Django 5+ default [protocol](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.protocol) is `https`

Comment: yes i came from google and its helped me thank you